# Finding Volume of Region Bounded by Two Planes and a Parabola

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $T$ be the region bounded by the surfaces $x = y^2, x+z = 1$ and $x-z = 1$. Find the volume of $T$.

I'm finding it very hard to figure out how to approach this problem and find the bounds and also which order to integrate in. My best attempt is writing $z$ in terms of $y$ by using the equations for the planes as $-1 +y^2 \leq z \leq 1 - y^2$, and $y$ in terms of $x$ as $-\sqrt{x} \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}$. Further, since we have $x = y^2$ we must have $x>0$. I really don't know how to find the upper bound for $x$ though. My best suggestion is to look at the intersection of the planes, which gives $$z = 1-x = x-1 \rightarrow x=  1.$$ This gives the integral $$V = \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_{y^2-1}^{1-y^2} dzdydx = \frac{32}{15},$$however the correct answer is $V = \frac{16}{15}$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute the volume of the set $T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x \leqslant 1 - z, x \leqslant 1 + z, x \geqslant y^2\}$. The first two inequalities can be rewritten as $z \leqslant 1 - x$ and $z \geqslant x - 1$, or in other words, $|z| \leqslant 1 - x$, which implies in particular that $x \leqslant 1$. Since $x \geqslant y^2 \geqslant 0$, you obtain that $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, thus $-\sqrt{x} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{x}$ (it implies that $y$ is between $-1$ and $1$ by the way) and $|z| \leqslant 1 - x$, thus,
$$
V = \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_{x - 1}^{1 - x} \, dz \, dy \, dx
$$
I don't understand why your bound on $z$ depends on $y$ because the conditions for being in $T$ are all expresses in function of $x$. Indeed, the point $(1,0,1)$ doesn't belong to $T$ because $z > 1 - x$ in this case, but this point verifies $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, $-\sqrt{x} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{x}$ and $y^2 - 1 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 - y^2$, which proves you intergate on a too large domain. Computing the integral, we indeed obtain,
\begin{align*}
V & = \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}} \int_{x - 1}^{1 - x} \, dz \, dy \, dx\\
& = \int_0^1 4(1 - x)\sqrt{x} \, dx\\
& = \int_0^1 4x^{1/2} - 4x^{3/2} \, dx\\
& = \left[4\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} - 4\frac{2}{5}x^{5/2}\right]_0^1\\
& = \frac{8}{3} - \frac{8}{5}\\
& = \frac{16}{15}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can I ask how you go from the equalities to inequalities? Also, are you saying my limits of integration imply that I'm integrating over the point $(1,0,1)$ which is not part of $T$?

Comment: I guessed the inequality, because if you reverse one, you obtain an unbounded region with infinite volume, but your question is not completely clear. Yes, it is what I mean